# htaccess add 301 moved permanently to RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have this rule in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

what it does is to redirect all url's index.php?somevar=# to index.php, however when it redirect's sends out code 302 and i want it to be 301.

I tried to add `[R=301]` after `RewriteRule . /index.php` but it doesn't work.

Some help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

This thing does not do what you describe. Your rule sends every request to **non-existent** files to `index.php`. The URL:

```
index.php?anything
```

already calls `index.php`. You don't need any rewrite magic to handle that.

Also ...

```
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

is a bad practice. It does not cause you problems now, but it could in the future, when you modify the rules. You'd rather use:

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```